# What is the proper way of executing a runtime upgrade on a parachain?

Tags: parachain, runtime-upgrade, wasm

I would like to upgrade my `parachain`.

What is the proper way of executing a runtime upgrade on a `parachain`?

Which `RPC method` to call?

Should this be applied to `collators` or rpc-nodes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The flow of upgrading the runtime in a parachain can definitely be different from the the flow one can be used to when running a solo chain.

For this scenario what is recommended is following the authorize --> enact path.

Note that the relay chain needs to be informed of the runtime upgrade before it happens, and just after that you could enact the upgrade in your para.

Cumulus provides these functionality in through pallet `cumulus-pallet-parachain-system` :

- [`authorize_uprgrade`](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/2fe7a2edba05155c6a5f0f3527e1001aad7aee2e/pallets/parachain-system/src/lib.rs#L387)
- [`enact_authorized_upgrade`](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/2fe7a2edba05155c6a5f0f3527e1001aad7aee2e/pallets/parachain-system/src/lib.rs#L397)

Please, find more details on [this how to guide](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/parachains/upgrade-a-parachain/)

Answer (score 7):

Just to add to the above answer: One good trick to providing the correct hash for `authorizeUpgrade`: you can select the "hash a file" option on the right and then pick a file on disk and it will compute the correct hash for you.

[image: authoriseUpgrade]

(but you do need to select the right file...)

Comment: `but you do need to select the right file...` --
This answer would be more usable if it explained which file to use...

Comment: For upgrading common good parachains the runtime file is built and released in the cumulus github; for example here is the v9290 release: https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/releases/tag/parachains-v9290 . Anyone can also build it themselves using the published docker image. Running https://github.com/chevdor/srtool-cli is the easiest way to do that.

Comment: I think `cargo build --release` in the correct source tree is the easiest and safest way. Then just picking the correct artifact is the challenge.