# How to make a parachain runtime upgrade

Tags: parachain, runtime-upgrade, substrate-parachain-template, cumulus

I´m trying to make a parachain runtime upgrade without a migration, as a way to understand the process before trying with a migration.

I´m using version 0.9.40 of polkadot for the relay chain and the parachain template with the same version.

As I understand the process it should be as follow:

- To make the upgrade in the parachain as in a solo chain, as explained here: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/upgrade-a-running-network/
- Then notify the relay chain of the upgrade via a priviledged transaction.

Is this correct?

I have seen other similar questions here but with a different extrinsic to be called, for example here: [What is the proper way of executing a runtime upgrade on a parachain?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/what-is-the-proper-way-of-executing-a-runtime-upgrade-on-a-parachain)  . AuthorizeUpgrade from parachainSystem is being called. I didn´t found something similar in the relay chain. What I have encountered that seems to be similar is: ForceScheduleCodeUpgrade from paras

[image]

In case I should use that, I don´t know how to get relayParentNumber to make the call.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should connect to your parachain node instead of the relaychain node. Because you want to upgrade the parachain. And the `ParachainSystem` only exists in parachain.

After that, follow the tutorial that you found. `authorize -> enact`.